# AWS CloudWatch alarm sends email when not all points are passed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to check if EC2 machines are on for more then 6 hours so I set a CloudWatch alarm to fire if `CPUUtilization > 0` for 24 periods of 15 min. The issue is that even if the machine is used for less, after it is switched off I receive emails like the following one. As you can see thethreshold was crossed only for 6 / 24 points. But I recevice the alarm anyway. Any clue what is going on here?

```
Alarm Details:
- Name:                       Machine up
- Description:                ATTENTION: the machine has been up for more than 6 hours.
- State Change:               INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> ALARM
- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 6 out of the last 24 datapoints were greater than or equal to the threshold (0.0). The most recent datapoints which crossed the threshold: [4.2 (26/09/19 13:16:00), 4.8 (26/09/19 13:01:00), 6.933333333333334 (26/09/19 12:46:00), 4.0 (26/09/19 12:31:00), 24.4 (26/09/19 12:16:00)] (minimum 24 datapoints for OK -> ALARM transition).
```

Comment: Your alarm configuration please

Comment: What do you mean? It is CPUUtilization >= 0 for 24 periods of 15 min. Btw I might have found a solution but I need to wait to test it. I had the alarm set to "Treat missing data as missing". I changed it to "Treat missing data as good". I think this will fix it even though I don't understand the observed behaviour with the "as missing" configuration.